# custom error response message/object with OpenApi

Tags: reactjs, react-native, openapi, openapi-generator

I use OpenApi generator on top of my frontend and backend.
When I call an api with invalid input I want the backend to return an error with feedback on the invalid input.
The error status code (HTTP status codes) is too broad, I want to return a custom error message or a simple object.
However, the error message/object gets removed by OpenApi

snippet from swagger

```
      responses:
        '200':
          description: OK
        '406':
          description: Not Acceptable
          content:
            application/json:
              schema:
                type: object
                title: ErrorResponseBody
                properties:
                  message:
                    type: string
                required:
                  - message
```

backend snippet

```
@app.put("/examplesnippet")
def examplesnippet():
    ...
    try:
        ...
    except RuntimeError as e:
        return ErrorResponseBody(str(e)).to_dict(), 406
    return {}, 200
```

frontend snippet

```
    new AccountApi(getApiConfiguration())
      .putAccountLicense({updateLicenseRequestBody: {licenseKey: newLicenseCode}})
      .then(response => {
        ...
      })
      .catch(error => {
        console.log(error);
        ...
      });
```

in Chrome, element inspect -> error object
[image]

in Chrome, element inspect -> Network -> Response

```
{
  "message": "InvalidLicense"
}
```